# rm -rf on vhosts directory, what should I do?

Tags: rm, data-recovery, chroot, plesk

I was tired and unfortunately I did:

```
rm -rf * /var/www/vhosts repertory
```

on my CentOS 6.3 running with Parallel Plesk.

I lost many websites, but worst: I've lost `chroot`, `default`, `fs` and `fs-passwd`.

What were these folders? 
What did they do?
What should I do now...?

I have backups, but only for my websites. I miss every file and folder that were in the `vhosts` directory (`chroot`,  `default`,  `fs` and  `fs-passwd`).

Comment: what was your working directory at the time you ran the command? the `*` is very important.

Comment: not sure about this, maybe others can comment/add more detail, but: would it be possible to use **data carving** to recover the deleted files? I'll do some more research for my own sake on this as well.

Comment: [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_Recovery) has a page about some recovery tools, including some that use data carving to restore deleted files/directories. It might be relevant to include your FS-type in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My content hoster helped me and found a solution, which might not work at 100% but 90% (100% is the total reload of the server).

First, since I had recreated a customized `/vhost/` directory with my backed up contents in there (it would not be your case), I deleted `/vhosts/`.

Second, I ran this from SSH: `usr/local/psa/bootstrapper/pp11.0.9-bootstrapper/bootstrapper.sh repair`

My hoster said:

> That utility should at least make Apache function normally again, but
>   there will be some oddities that can't be avoided. Plesk will
>   sometimes be able to recover the metadata and recreate them without
>   content.

So, I recreated the subscriptions/webspaces on Plesk.
Then I used the backups to restore the subscriptions/webspaces to their original condition.

> You may sometimes find when recreating the subscription/webspace that
>   the user account already exists. This is because the bootstrap repair
>   didn't leave a clean slate in Plesk. You'll need to edit the `psa`
>   database and look for the username under the `sys_users` table and
>   delete it. If Plesk still complains about the user, delete the actual
>   account from SSH,
>   he added.